# Prove $QBQx = Qc$ has one, and only one, solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling

**The problem**

Let
$$ B = \left( \begin{array}{c c c} 
1 & 0.5 & 0.2 \\
0.5 & 1 & 0.5 \\
0.2 & 0.5 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) $$
Let $I = \left\{ 1,3 \right\}.$ We define $Q = (q_{i,j})$ s.t $q_{i,j} = 1$ if $i = j \in I$ and $q_{i,j} = 0,$ otherwise. Let $c = (1,1,1)$ and $x$ a vector.

Show $QBQx = Qc$, with $Qx = x$, has one, and only one, solution.

**My works**

I found
$$ Q = \left( \begin{array}{c c c} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) $$
Then
$$ QBQ = \left( \begin{array}{c c c} 
1 & 0 & 0.2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0.2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) $$
But $QBQ$ is not inversible. I don't understand how we can show the equation $QBQx = Qc$ has one solution...

Thank you

Comment: I think you are right. It has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, we have to satisfy 2 conditions:$QBQx=Qc$ and $Qx=x$. 
Let $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)'$, then from $Qx=x$, we have $x_2 =0$. 
Now consider, $QBQx=Qc$, then $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0.2\\0&0&0\\0.2&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1+0.2x_3\\0\\0.2x_1+x_3 \end{pmatrix}$
This gives $x_1=\frac{80}{96}, x_3=\frac{160}{192}$.

Comment: I was totally focused on QBQx = Qc that I’ve forgot Qx=x. I was not thinking Qx=x will be useful. Thank you so much !